# Error implementing projectile motion to ball

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to do an exercise where i must implement projectile motion to a ball generated on click, and everytime it touches a margin the speed must be reduced by 10% and should reverse direction.

The movement and the colision on the x axis are fine i think, but i cant make the colision on the y axis work.

Global vars:

```
  {
      ctx: null,
      screenWidth: window.innerWidth - 50,
      screenHeight: window.innerHeight - 50,
      ballsArray: [],
      gravity: -10
  }
```

Draw method:

```
    draw() { //draw ball logic
      this.ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
      this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.screenWidth, this.screenHeight);

      //for each ball in the array
      this.ballsArray.forEach(ball => {
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.fillStyle = ball.color;

        ball.time += 0.01;

        //saves new position for each axis
        let newPosX = ball.posX + ball.velX * ball.time;
        let newPosY =
          ball.posY + ball.velY - 0.5 * this.gravity * Math.pow(ball.time, 2);

        //checks if in the new position the ball will collide with margins
        //if so, it must slows down and get the inverse direction
                 if ( //colision on x axis
          newPosX <= ball.radius ||
          newPosX >= this.screenWidth - ball.radius
        ) {
          ball.velX = -ball.velX * 0.9;
        }
        if (newPosY <= ball.radius) { //colision on top
          // ball.velY = Math.abs(ball.velY * 0.9);
          ball.velY = -ball.velY * 0.9;
        }
        if (newPosY >= this.screenHeight - ball.radius) { //colition on bottom
          // ball.velY = -Math.abs(ball.velY * 0.9);          
          ball.velY = -ball.velY * 0.9;
        }

        //updates de new position for each axis
        newPosX = ball.posX + ball.velX * ball.time;
        newPosY =
          ball.posY + ball.velY - 0.5 * this.gravity * Math.pow(ball.time, 2);

        //assigns the new positions to the position
        ball.posX = newPosX;
        ball.posY = newPosY;

                //draws the ball
        this.ctx.arc(ball.posX, ball.posY, ball.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        this.ctx.closePath();
        this.ctx.fill();
      });
```

Create ball method

```
    createBall() { //create a new ball
      let newBall = { //local vars
        id: this.ballsArray.length + 1,
        color: this.getRandomColor(),
        radius: 10,
        posX: this.screenWidth / 2,
        posY: this.screenHeight / 1.5,
        velX: Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) - 5, //random between -5 and 5
        velY: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 10, //random between -5 and 0
        time: 0,
      };
      this.ballsArray.push(newBall); //add the ball to the array of balls
    }
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pedroguia/y123spjh/77/

As you can see, the ball goes through the bottom margin. I'm not sure if the problem lies on the equations or the collision detection itself.

Answer (score 0):

This works but with the amendments below. Hope that helps.

https://jsfiddle.net/ferjb716/

I do not know how this part is supposed to work so I simplified it.
I'd be interested in how to do it with the original values.

```
  let newPosY =
          ball.posY + ball.velY - 0.5 * this.gravity * Math.pow(ball.time, 2);
```

Simplifying it to

```
 let newPosY = ball.posY + ball.velY * ball.time
```

worked

Also these look like errors

**Errors**

from: velX

```
if (newPosY <= ball.radius) { //collision on top
      // ball.velY = Math.abs(ball.velY * 0.9);
      ball.velY = -ball.velX * 0.9;
    }

if (newPosY >= this.screenHeight - ball.radius) { //collision on bottom
  // ball.velY = -Math.abs(ball.velY * 0.9);          
  ball.velY = -ball.velX * 0.9;
}
```

changed to velY

```
 if (newPosY <= ball.radius) { //colision on top
          // ball.velY = Math.abs(ball.velY * 0.9);
          ball.velY = -ball.velY * 0.9;  //correction
        }

 if (newPosY >= this.screenHeight - ball.radius) { //colition on bottom
          // ball.velY = -Math.abs(ball.velY * 0.9);          
          ball.velY = -ball.velY * 0.9;   //correction
        }
```

Comment: It does indeed work, always colide with the bottom margin, but its not moving according to the projectile motion anymore, and thats the main point.
Thanks for pointing out the errors.

Comment: where did you get your information for projectile motion ?